# Up to parent activity - on Android

Tags: android, android-activity

After receiving a notification in my app, clicking on it opens activity B. Activity B has a parent activity A. Here is the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.evapp.activities.B"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_B"
    android:parentActivityName="com.evapp.activities.A"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.evapp.activities.A" />
</activity>
```

In activity B I have the up functionality enabled (left arrow near the activity action's bar icon), here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
```

The problem is that if activity B was opened via clicking on the notification (activity A was not the one to bring activity B) the when clicking on the icon the app is closed. I would like to make it open it's parent activity, A. Is it possible? or should I do it with `startActivity()` from activity B?

**Update 1-** I have added this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
   switch (item.getItemId()) 
   {
       case android.R.id.home:
            Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent))
            {
                TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                    .startActivities();
            } 
            else 
            {
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
            }

            return true;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set up the `PendingIntent` which is used to build `Notification`, to start a fresh task, and provide the `PendingIntent` with a `back stack` to achieve the application's normal Up behavior.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// All the parents of SecondActivity will be added to task stack.
stackBuilder.addParentStack(SecondActivity.class);
// Add a SecondActivity intent to the task stack.
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

// Obtain a PendingIntent for launching the task constructed by this builder.
PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(REQUEST_CODE, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("My Notification")
    .setContentText("Notification content")
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .build();

manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Please read the Android official documentation on **[Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse)**. It recommends the above approach.

Comment: While using TaskStackBuilder, Do not forget to add Parent activity declaration in Manifest.

Comment: Also don't forget to use if(NavUtils.getParentActivityName( this ) != null ) NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask( this ); in your onBackPressed() in the Activity, or when finishing the Activity from a fragment. If the if statement fails, then use super.onBackPressed or finish().

Comment: It seems to not work on Android 7.0 (Nexus 5X). Any idea ?

Comment: How do we deliver changes of B to A if A started B for result and this time B started from Notification?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code and it works like a charm. Have a go!

```
Intent upIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
    Log.d("ShowNotifications", "New Home");
    TaskStackBuilder.create(this).addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent).startActivities();
} else {
    Log.d("ShowNotifications", "Old Home");
    upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    //upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
    startActivity(upIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ParentActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

val secondIntent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
         addNextIntentWithParentStack(secondIntent)
         getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
```

The `TaskStackBuilder` **parentStack** solution only works for `Android < 7.` For **Android 7+** I think you should add both parentActivity and secondActivity to the **TaskStack**.

```
val parentIntent = Intent(this, ParentActivity::class.java)
val secondIntent = Intent(this, SecondIntent::class.java)
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
        addNextIntent(parentIntent)
        addNextIntent(secondIntent)
        getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an temporary activity to launch when the notification is clicked (without using  setContentView). There you can decide which activity to launch. Depending on your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Up to parent activity - on Android

Simply you can start activity parent activity with some boolean argument and if boolean argument is set in activity b then launch activity A. This way both activities will be live on stack or use taskstackbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

While using [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html), Do not forget to add Parent activity declaration in Manifest.

For API 16 + :

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
... />
```

For API < 16

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".MainActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If @Manish Mulimani's solution worked for you, then please feel free to ignore this information. It didn't work for me, and I haven't tried the code that is in OP, but here is an alternate solution if neither of those worked for you:

First, as OP did, specify the parent Activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".DetailActivity"
    android:label="@string/activity_detail"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Then, in the code you write to show your notification, do the following:

```
/* The Intent you want to open when your notification is clicked */
Intent detailIntent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
/* If you have some extras or a URI, set it here for the DetailActivity */
detailIntent.setData(todaysWeatherUri);

/*
 * This Intent is the one that goes back to your MainActivity when the up 
 * arrow or back button is clicked from the DetailActivity. 
 */
Intent backToMain = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
                .addNextIntentWithParentStack(backToMain)
                .addNextIntent(detailIntent)
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I've tested this with every iteration of starting Activities that I can thin of and it works perfectly! I hope it helps you.

[Here is the link for the Android Documentation from where I formed this solution.](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#SynthesizeBackStack)