# Back button on app takes me off the actual app

Tags: android

An issue with the back button on the actual app. Once the app is killed and we receive a message and open it via the notification and then select the back button it takes me off the actual app rather than onto the conversation thread.

This app is a server communication app.

Current code on the ConversationActivity

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ConversationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

If we use the back button on the phone it takes you back to the mainActivity but if we use the back button on the app, it takes you off the actual app, which isn't what we want.

Comment: `ConversationActivity` was started from `MainActivity` ? If so, only a `finish()` should do the work. Also, make sure you're overriding the `onBackPressed()` method, just to make sure that is called when the back button is touched.

Comment: Apologies I'm very new to Android Studio, and as a developer. Can please explain in more detail plus maybe some example code or fixes? Thank you

Comment: Sure, no prob. Check my answer :)

Comment: Sorry have you put the answer up? Thanks

Comment: Obvious question, but is `MainActivity` the parent of `ConversationActivity` in your Manifest?

Comment: @A.Samad I did, check below

Comment: Ok this link will help you - make sure your pending intent in the notification has a back stack - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23466841/4252352 then you won't need to override `onBackPressed()`

Comment: I think your right mark, but i really I'm not sure how to go about this entirely. Extremely new to programming. Thanks

Comment: There's a good video here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WozSRUnYoNM that goes through the basics of notifications, which you can then easily translate into your project, and if in any doubt always refer to the documentation first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `startActivity()` method, the `Activity` from where you call it, becomes like a parent of the newly started activity, for example:

```
public void goAnotherAct(View v) {
   Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.this);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

In this snippet, `Activity1` becomes the 'father' of `Activity2`, so if you call the `finish()` method in `Activity2`, it should return to the 'father' activity, which is `Activity1`. 
What I meant with overriding the super class method, is that if you don't there might be a chance that the method will not be used. You must declare the `onBackPressed()` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: The `onBackPressed()` method handles the phones' back button.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the

```
OnBackPressed()
```

in the Back button click Event in the APP.
And your OnBackPressed will be..

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}
```

Comment: Apologies not sure what you exactly mean?

Comment: I mean that, Call this method on the back button click in the App.

Comment: Ah sorry i read that wrong. Unfortunately there is not back button click located on this app? which is weird?